# Is there any way to append File-List to FormData() in Angular 8

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

```
registrationWithMultipart(access_token: any, body: any, multipart: Array<File>) {

let formData = new FormData();
if (body) formData.append('applicationInfoDto', JSON.stringify(body));
if (multipart) formData.append('img', multipart);

return this.http.post(config.url + '/application/xxxxx?access_token=' + access_token, formData);
}
```

Comment: can u explain what u r trying to implement ?

Comment: I think you are asking the multiple file need to append in form data If yes then you need to iterate a loop and append the object and pass the form data in post.